# Default view does not show when deploying HotTowel SPA to IIS

Tags: angularjs, iis, visual-studio-2013, breeze

I have a SPA project in VS 2013 using Angular.js and HotTowel and Breeze.  It works fine on my development machine but when I deploy it to IIS 8.0 on a webserver running Windows Server 2012 it fails.  The framework loads but it does not load my default view.  It simply flashes the splash page and shows an empty browser.

I can walk through the js code using the Developer Tools but it never loads my default view into the index.html.

Using the developer tools in IE, I set breakpoints in the config.route.js to walk through the process of determining what page will be loaded into the SPA.  It appears to be coming up with the correct page. The page that is supposed to load is called request.html so I also placed a breakpoint in the request.js to see if it was failing on the load.  It never hits this breakpoint.

I am hoping that perhaps somebody has run into these same or similar issues when deploying an SPA to IIS.

Thanks for any help that can be given.  In the meantime, I will keep searching.

JG

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: When I run this locally through Visual Studio, the default view displays properly.  When I publish it to IIS on our QA web server, the index page loads but the default view does not show.  I have turned on errors in the web.config but no errors are being thrown, it just throws up a blank page

Comment: That is a problem, not a question.  It is hard to guess what you may be doing wrong because there are no questions nor code in your question, only generic statements of what is occurring.

Comment: I did not post any code because this appears to be a deployment issue as opposed to a coding issue.  The app works fine locally on all of our machines (there are 4 developers working on the project using VS 2013).  I created a web application in IIS 8.0 on MS Server 2012 then deployed it using the Publish functionality in Visual Studio.  I guess I was hoping that someone else had run into this issue and knew how to resolve it.  I do appreciate your patience and your quick response to my question.

Comment: Sure, I am pointing this out because you are much more likely to get helpful responses on this site when you form questions that show steps to recreate the issue.  As it stands your question is vague and hard to help you find resolution for.

Comment: *Ok, I have determined what is causing he problem as well as an unacceptable workaround. I opened the site in Chrome and then opened the developer tools.  When I went to the Console tab I discovered the following error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) `http://localhost/app/layout/shell.html`

Comment: The path should be:
    http://localhost/businessfunctions/app/layout/shell.html
The site I created on IIS was called business functions.  I used the File System method to publish from Visual Studio.
The code in my index.html that references this is: 

<div data-ng-include="'/app/layout/shell.html'"></div>

Comment: I came up with a workaround manually a by copying the entire app folder to the wwwroot.  I know it is not acceptable but it does fix the problem.  I then tried using a web deploy but it did the same thing.  Still trying to figure out the proper way of deploying this so if anybody has any ideas, let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Success at last! As stated in the comments I found there were some path issues in the index.html.  I managed to fix the problem by removing the leading '\' from the data-ng-include for the shell.html.

Was:

```
<div data-ng-include="'/app/layout/shell.html'"></div>
```

Now:

```
<div data-ng-include="'app/layout/shell.html'"></div>
```

This enabled the code to find the proper directory level for the shell.html.  I was concerned that this would break the code for the dev environment but it works fine.

I then found that I needed to fix similar paths in the directives.js file in the function for the ccWidgetHeader.  The templateUrl had to be modified.

Was:

```
/app/layout/widgetheader.html
```

Now:

```
app/layout/widgetheader.html
```

Finally I had to modify the style.css to fix a path for a logo image in the header.

Was:

```
.navbar .brand {
background: url(/content/images/fcma-biostar.png) no-repeat left center !important;
margin-left: -6px;
padding: 35px 50px;
```

}

Now:

```
.navbar .brand {
background: url(images/fcma-biostar.png) no-repeat left center !important;
margin-left: -6px;
padding: 35px 50px;
```

}

**Many Thanks! to PW Kad and fops for chiming in on this issue!**

Comment: John Papa is a genius, and should be forgiven for such a small oversight.  Thanks for finding it :)

Answer (score -1):

well just a guess, of course a blank screen can be caused by way more reasons that the one mentioned here.
in my case i had to turn off the minification in the BundleConfig.cs code:

```
  BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

(consider this as a workaround. To fix it definitely its worth a try to check the dependency injection part of your angular code)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Unfortunately, we are not doing any bundling yet.  This is our first angular application and we are very early in the dev process.  I am just trying to get it deployed so that our QA Analyst can demo the concept to the users.